# Computationally singular matrix inverse error?

Tags: r, matrix, singular

This error comes up when I am dividing by the matrix inverse.

````
 Error in solve.default(x) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.85861e-18 ```
````

What are the ways to solve this? I am using the matrix.inverse function to find the inverse.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. This message means that your matrix is very (very !) badly contionned, and that numerically computing its inverse would make little sense (see `?rcond`). You might want to use instead the pseudoinverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a matrix `M`, I guess it would be safe to use `ginv` from package `MASS` to compute the inverse if you want to avoid the error in your post, e.g.,

```
MASS::ginv(M)
```